# Unhelpful error message when proposing an overlong tag synonym

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, tag-synonyms, error-message

If you try to propose a tag synonym longer than the maximum of 25 characters, it displays the error message:

[image: Error message screenshot]

> Failed to propose synonym:
>
> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

This looks like a raw database error message. It should be changed to say something helpful, like

> Tag names have a maximum of 25 characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

New error message:

> The tag '(suggested synonym)' is too long; the maximum length is 25 characters

This will be in the next build.